# CRAFT_BASE_PATH problems when installing Craft 3 in subdirectory

Tags: craft3

My client wants Craft 3 installed in a subdirectory of the main site. So I placed it in http://mainsite.com/subdir.

The issue now is that the webroot for the domain is at http://mainsite.com, so my Craft `index.php` isn't being hit when I go to http://mainsite.com/subdir since it's further down in the `/web` folder.

I'm trying to pull my `index.php` out of `/web` and into the `/subdir` directory by setting a custom `CRAFT_BASE_PATH`, but I've tried several different paths to no avail.

The error is simply: "This page isn’t working. mainsite.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

My directory structure is:

```
var/www/html/subdir/
├── craft/
│   └── config, vendor, templates, .env, web etc
├── index.php
```

But if it would be better if I stuffed `index.php` back into `/web` and went about this a different way I'm all ears. I'm not the network admin, so if there is a way to set a custom root for a subdirectory on the server or something, I'll have to ask someone else to do it for me, which is fine if that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, take the content of `web` and place it in `subdir` so you have:

```
html/
├── subdir/
│   └── craft/ (config, vendor, templates, .env etc)
│   └── cpresources
│   └── .htaccess
│   └── index.php
└── the main site
```

Then in `index.php` do :

`define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/subdir/craft');`

And you should have your craft site accessible at `mainsite.com/subdir`